# Can Mirth send JavaBeans on JMS?

Tags: java, jms, javabeans, mirth

I would like to send a Java Bean down a JMS queue to a destination using Mirth.  Is this possible?  Anyone have any examples?

I've seen a few questions regarding Mirth and JMS and even fewer answers. :-(

The Edit Channel -> Script tab pre and post processors have a "Use Java Class" selection on the right hand selections.  It produces:

```
var object = Packages.[fully-qualified name];
```

So I can get a js version of a Java Class (just attributes? I would assume so).  Once populating the js/Java object can it be sent to a destination via JMS?

I've googled a lot today but there doesn't seem to be a lot of info on Mirth.  If you could point me to some good docs/examples it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Andrew

Answer (score 0):

It seems this is one of the interesting topics not very well covered. Possible steps are, assuming that there are two channels, one is playing role of the JMS sender and another is the JMS listener, with the Message Broker in between:

- JAR the class that implements Serializable interface and move to the custom-lib.
- On the sender's side, create an instance of the object and populate required fields;
- Serialize the object (using org.apache.commons. lang3.SerializationUtils.serialize for example);
- Encode the result (using Mirth built-in Base64 encoder);
- Pass this to the destination connector which is configured as the JMS Sender.

On the receiver side do the same in a reverse order:

- Decode the received raw message (using Mirth built-in Base64 decoder);
- Deserialize the byte array into the object (using the org.apache.commons.lang3.SerializationUtils.deserialize);
- Access object's fields.

(PS. The last but not least, all steps in detail to send and receive Java objects via the ActiveMQ, with screenshots and code snippets, are given in the “[Unofficial Mirth Connect Developer's Guide](http://mirthconnect.shamilpublishing.com)”.)